# increasing GET data in url

Tags: php, html

how can i increase the data that the GEt(not POST) method can send?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Redefine the http standard, create your own nuHTTP server, build your own browser and start playing with your friends..

Comment: On the client-side with `opera:config` and "Maximum length of url" (mine is 2GB). And for the server-side, make a PHP daemon script, listen to a separate port, receive and parse HTTP GET requests yourself. For other servers: out of luck.

Comment: If the limit is to small then stop sending the data with the HTTP request and send a reference to the data, like a URI.  Then make your script, or whatever, download the contents of the URI and process that data.  Obvious security checks assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no control over the limitations of the GET request.

There are limitations in various browsers (some as low as 255 characters) and also limitations imposed by a server, but normally more than 255 characters.

So you will need to think of another way of indexing your content that doesn't require such massive URLs. 255 characters is quite a lot for a normal GET request - so you are probably trying to do something other than just serve a page.

Please give more information about why you need longer URLs and we may be able to offer a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
registration-sucsess.php?type=Full Payment&product_id=aa
```

here we are passing two variables type and product_id